# ASP.NET MVC3 IIS7.5: Cache-Control maxage is always 0 (not good for client-side caching)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching

I was testing my website with Fiddler and noticed that web server always returns

```
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
```

for dynamic content (MVC actions). This prevents pages from being cached on client side. I wonder if it is problem of MVC or IIS. How can I fix it? I really need client-side caching to work.

Thank you!

P.S. Below is the full set of response headers:

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, s-maxage=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-UA-Compatible: IE=edge,Chrome=1
Date: Sun, 20 Nov 2011 23:07:46 GMT
Content-Length: 2050

Comment: Curious. I had exactly the opposite problem. MVC 3 running on IIS7.5 added cache-control:private to every action, thereby caching every page in the browser. Solved it using a global output cache filter. I didn't figure out what was setting it in the first place though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [OutputCacheAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx) on your controllers and/or actions to set the cache policy for that controller's actions or a particular action.

```
 [OutputCache( Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, Duration = 600 )]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
    ..
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for response! I actually wrote a custom filter, just forgot that ASPNET had output caching out of the box :)

Comment: By way way, what does s-maxage=0 stand for? It is 0 even if caching is enabled.

Comment: For a shared cache (proxy) it specifies that it should use this value rather than the max-age value: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.3